# Aurigma Html5/Flash Uploader, browser supporting issue

Tags: html, uploader, aurigma

I have been trying aurigma html5 uploader in IE10. It was working fine.
But when i switch the browser mode from IE10 to IE9, it shows a message as "Browser is not supported".
Can anybody tell me which are browsers and in what browser's version the aurigma uploader is supported.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

IE9 has very limited HTML5 support making Aurigma HTML5 Uploader unable to work in that browser. Aurigma Upload Suite (HTML5 Uploader is a part of this solution) comes with Flash Uploader which can be used as a fallback option in old browsers where the HTML5 solution cannot work. Feel free to contact Aurigma support team if you need help to configure your uploader.